# Is it Possible to Hybrid Crossfire Radeon 5650 and 5670 graphics cards?

Tags: amd-radeon, crossfire

I have a Radeon 5650 graphics card which is very rare now. I wonder if I can crossfire a 5650 to work with a 5670 which is cheap and available. If I can crossfire them, will there be a performance impact and will there be any [microstutter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_stuttering)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's no 5650 and my card is 5670. I'm a dumbass :)

Same thing happened when I mixed up my core count and RAM amount. I have a Phenom II x6 1100T and 8GBs of ram. For a long time I thought I had 8 cores and 6GBs of RAM. One day I was adjusting something in the BIOS settings and I saw tempeatures: Core #0..#6 and I realised I had a 6 core processor. (/.-)

Answer (score 1):

Your card is not mentioned specifically, but there is a compatibility table [here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/245454-15-crossfire-faqs). It seems different cards can work together in a crossfire setup, provided they are within the same *hundred* family. For instance any 69xx will work with any other 69xx, but not a 68xx card.

Be sure to check that your card is crossfire capable before buying a second one.

Comment: Yes, 5670 is CrossFireX compatible but I'm not sure about the 5650(damn, even AMD site doesn't have information about it). I'll just assume that it has CrossFireX support too simply because they are both 56xx. I could look for a CrossFireX port right now but I'm too lazy. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: And, BTW, I asked what would happen if I crossfired those. And by "why", I know that it will be faster. I just want to know how both cards react.

Comment: I'm sorry but I really can't predict microstutter issues. There seems to be very little known about what the exact cause is.

Comment: Thanks for your help then! I'll buy it and see(it's about 49 dollars here so I wouldn't be bankrupt if it doesn't perform well) :)

Comment: If it does not work you should at least be able to return it for what you paid minus postage and possibly a restocking fee.